# How Yelp System Detects Paid Reviews

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, feature-extraction, anomaly-detection, sentiment-analysis

I am wondering how the yelp spam detection system detects paid reviews? By paid, I mean the following scenarios:

1. I as a business owner pay people to write positive comments and give me a good rate
2. I as a business owner pay people to write negative comments against my opponent businesses.

I appreciate any technical response and also the introduction of good resources. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the system looks deeper into the user's profile. If the user's comments are more frequent on a specific company. Instead of giving a different comment, he/she is always targetting a specific company in the comment.